What does "beat his man" mean in sport?
I don't understand the word "man" used in this match report. Here's a match coverage from the English Premier league. Does it mean "player" in this context?

GOAL! Newcastle 0-1 Man City (GVARDIOL, 35 mins) Breakthrough - and
it's from the visitors. Jack Grealish is the architect down the left,
beating his man before slipping the ball through to Josko Gvardiol.
The full-back does the hard part, though, taking on his marker before
finding the bottom corner.


Yes, it means his immediate opponent.

His man is literally a male player. So man=player and player=man. Per @Peter, the word his shows the immediacy. The other player is not his in any other way that we'd know, or judge.

4 b " one of the players on a team"

It means getting out in front of him. Being faster than him.

Hello Shakila,  are you generally familiar with the game of "football" (ie soccer).  Do you know the rules of the game, and how it is played?  If you don't know how to play football, this must seem very hard to understand. Football commentary uses lots of specialist vocabulary that is specific to football.  Do you know how a football team will defend by "marking man-to-man"?

Here beating his man means beating his marker, that Newcastle guy.

If so what's the difference "man" and "marker"? That's what I'm confused by.

@Shakila, They're both nouns and refer to the same person.  It's just a choice of words.  The commentator could've said beating his marker or beating the Newcastle number X.
